# How can I make my JS variables refer dynamically to DOM elements instead of simply saving their properties

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a large table of `<div>`s on a page which get updated via JS all the time. Now I am writing a Chrome Extension to read these updates. At some point I'll have to refer to these `<div>` elements and their `innerHTML`. For some reasons, I'd rather save this whole table into one simple array, and then later update the array with the `innerHTML` of its elements. So I assign
`savedElement = document.getElementById("ID1");` and later use `console.log(savedElement.innerHtml);`, However, the output is always the initiated value of the original Dom element, and never changes.
I know, when assigning a new object to a variable, the properties of the object are all copied to the variable, and future references to that variable will not output different values not matter how many times the actual DOM element has been changed.

**Now, How can I save these DOM elements into my JS variables in a way that does not just keep those variables in their initiated state,  but rather changes dynamically every time the DOM element is called through the variable?**

```
console.log (dElement.innerHtml); // output Hello World
wait (3000); // this element "Obj1" is changed in the meanthile
console.log (dElement.innerHtml); // output Hello World
```

The problem is, as the above shows, the value of Obj1 doesn't change even if its value has been modified on the DOM itself. This output must also be synced.

*Not: please let me know how to save a DOM element into a variable in a way that its innerHTML keeps updating and not just showing the initiated value.*

Comment: Sounds like the element has been *replaced*, so you'll have to select it again